# Error while trying to create dashcast stream using libx265

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265, dashcast

I'm trying to create a h265 encoded stream from webcam using the follwoing command.

```
DashCast -vf video4linux2  -v4l2f mjpeg -v /dev/video0 -conf dashcast.conf -live-media
```

The content if dashcast.conf is

```
[v1]
type=video
codec=libx265
bitrate=1000000
framerate=25
width=640
height=480
```

But I'm getting this error.

```
Options:
    video source: /dev/video0
    video format: video4linux2
    v4l2 format: mjpeg
    video crop: 0x0
    audio source: 
Configurations:
    id:v1   res:640x480 vbr:1000000
[mjpeg @ 0xb194e0] Changeing bps to 8
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 50349.327770, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, -5 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
AVCTX give frame duration of 1/1000000 - keeping requested rate -1, but this may result in unexpected behaviour.
[swscaler @ 0xb91ea0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Press q or Q to exit...
[dashcast] Live system dropped a video frame
[dashcast] Live system dropped a video frame
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 1.8+1-5dcc9d3a928c400b
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 4.8.4][64 bit] 8bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-3 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 4 threads
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 1 / wpp(8 rows)
[dashcast] Live system dropped a video frame
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut       : 25 / 250 / 40
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / 0 / 0
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 1 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : ABR-1000 kbps / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=0.30 signhide tmvp strong-intra-smoothing
x265 [info]: tools: deblock sao
Cannot parse HEVC/H265 SPS/PPS
Bad Parameter: dc_gpac_video_write_config
Bad Parameter: gf_isom_start_segment
Cannot open output video file.
Generating MPD at 2015-11-24T19:17:46.040Z
StartTime: 2015-11-24T19:17:46.040Z - startNumber 1 - last number 1
Keyboard thread exit
[dashcast] Live system dropped a video frame
[dashcast] Live system dropped a video frame
```

What could be the problem? Changing codec to libx264 in the conf file works fine.